# How to limit height of div when part of 2 vertical divs in fixed parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar which contains two divs.

The sidebar itself is position:fixed.

The first div has a relatively small height and is likely to always fit in the screen.
The second div however may contain many elements, so it exceeds the browser windows' height.

How must I style my CSS so that the second div limits its height to fit the overall height including a vertical scrollbar?

Check out this fiddle for more information: https://jsfiddle.net/riemersebastian/6fsszjt6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar-left">
  <div class="nonscrollable-header">

      I want the content in yellow div
      always to be visible and not move;
      the content in orange should be in a div with a vertical scrollbar<br>
      I don't want to specify any absolute heights or margins etc.
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable-content-exceeding-height">
  Here is the content I want to be in scrollable div instead of exceeding the height.
  <ul>
  <li>here is lots of content which i want to be in a vertical scrollable div</li>
  <li>it obiously should not exceed the height of the window</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sidebar-left {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}

.nonscrollable-header {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.scrollable-content-exceeding-height {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Please note that I dislike setting any absolute height values.

Comment: Do you want Pure CSS solution or you have the option of using javascript?

Comment: I don't want to use Javascript nor JQuery for this task, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using [Flexible box layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) is an option, it can be achieved by changing the `display` type of the sidebar to `flex` along with specifying the direction of flex items as `column`. So that we can make the second child element fill the remaining height by setting its `flex-grow` property to `1`.

Finally, we can add the scroll-bar UI when needed by setting the `overflow` property of that flex item to `auto`:

```css
.sidebar-left {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scrollable-content-exceeding-height {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Notice: vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity. Flexbox syntax has been changed multiple times during the time. For better [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) you should add specific vendor prefixes/versions.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar-left {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nonscrollable-header {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.scrollable-content-exceeding-height {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-left">
  <div class="nonscrollable-header">
    
      I want the content in yellow div
      always to be visible and not move;
      the content in orange should be in a div with a vertical scrollbar<br>
      I don't want to specify any absolute heights or margins etc.
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable-content-exceeding-height">
  Here is the content I want to be in scrollable div instead of exceeding the height.
  <ul>
  <li>here is lots of content which i want to be in a vertical scrollable div</li>
  <li>it obiously should not exceed the height of the window</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  <li>here is lots of content</li>
  </ul>
  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hashem, your solution looks very good, I'll have to check with the browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Predict the .nonscrollable-header height based on its content and set it statically( For Ex. 100px). Then set .scrollable-content-exceeding-height's height with following code...

```
.scrollable-content-exceeding-height{
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: I see that this could work, +1 for the calc function, thanks! However I prefer the solution with flexible box layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
.scrollable-content-exceeding-height {
  background-color: orange;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height:300px;
}
```

Edit max-height to whatever you want, use jquery as answer below shows to make the div the height of window.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to hardcode the height, you can use this jquery way to set the height.

https://jsfiddle.net/6fsszjt6/7/

```
code
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property you are looking for is **overflow**.
'

```css
.sidebar-left {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
}

.nonscrollable-header {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.scrollable-content-exceeding-height {
  background-color: orange;
  overflow:auto;
  max-height:100px;
}
```

Here the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9cg6f181/)

Hope it's answer to your question :)

Remy